# Does IE 6/7/8 have an addon that is similar to "Web Developer" for Firefox?

Tags: browser-addons, internet-explorer-8, javascript, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am looking for the same JavaScript functionality (Errors/Warnings/etc.) that the Web Developer add-on for Firefox has. Does such a thing exist and where can I find it?

Comment: Any web developer tools for IE6/7?

Comment: As you're only referring to the Web Developer toolbar: you know about that other must-have Firefox add-on, Firebug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&DisplayLang=en) for IE but I doubt it allows you to debug JavaScript.

A better version of which is already integrated in IE 8 (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>). It definitely includes debugging functionality for JavaScript, including breakpoints and all:

[image: Internet Explorer 8 Developer Tools]

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60

Comment: Thanks for the link but a short explanation what exactly it does what interests you would have been easier. I can't install FF at work anyway.

Comment: Sorry, basically I am looking for the same functionality to debug JavaScript in IE 6/7/8

Comment: In that case you're out of luck on IE 6/7 but you can have fun on IE 8 without installing anything additionally.

Answer (score 3):

IE8 has the **Developer Tools** feature built-in.

You can access it by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or the "Developer Tools" entry in the Tools menu.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) has some of the functionality you are looking for.